# I’m trying to get a button to copy the output of my date script and ad what it produces into the clipboard. Can someone help please?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>

<div id="current_date"></p>


<script>


date = new Date();

year = date.getFullYear();

month = date.getMonth() + 1;

day = date.getDate();

document.getElementById("current_date").inn

erHTML = year + "-" + day+ "-" + month;


</script>


<button>Copy Date</button>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've already figured out how to get the Date in the format you want, however, you want to use `.value` and not `.innerHTML` to get the text into the input. innerHTML is used for divs, spans and other elements while value applies to any element where its value can be defined (textbox, etc...).

```
document.getElementById("current_date").value = year + "-" + day+ "-" + month;
```

Once it's in the input you just need to select it. The `setSelectionRange` is redundant on desktops but is useful for mobiles as not all of them accept `.select()`. Then the last line copies the selection into the clipboard.

```
copyText.select();
copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999);
navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value);
```

Here's the code:

```
     date = new Date(); 
     year = date.getFullYear(); 
     month = date.getMonth() + 1; 
     day = date.getDate(); 

    document.getElementById("current_date").value = year + "-" + day+ "-" + month;

    var copyText = document.getElementById("current_date");
    copyText.select();
    copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999);
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value);
```